# Setting acronyms to appear as a footnotes in margin cause Marginpar moved warning

Tags: footnotes, glossaries, warnings, marginpar, acronyms

I am using glossaries package with the acronym and footnote option. I also set footnotes to appear in the margin. With multiple acronyms in a line, multiple footnotes are placed in the margin. To avoid overlap, the notes are moved which causes Marginpar moved warning.

Is there a way to prevent Marginpar warnings when multiple notes are generated in the margin corresponding to content from a single line?

Answer (score 2):

Your question does not provide your technical solution which leads to the warnings. That said: give the `marginfix`-package a try (`\usepackage{marginfix}` before `\begin{document}`).

Comment: marginfix did indeed fix it! I didn't think my problem was covered by the fix, but it seems to have done the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You just want to remove the warning, not stop them moving? If that is what you meant then:

```
\makeatletter

\def\foo#1\@latex@warning@no@line#2#3\@nil{\def\@addmarginpar{#1#3}}
\expandafter\foo\@addmarginpar\@nil

\makeatother
```

Comment: The [`silence` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/silence) also has this "muting" capability.